# Does the action have to be coordinate invariant?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, action, diffeomorphism-invariance

Is the Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$ in the action $S=\int d^4x \sqrt{-g}\mathcal{L}$ required to be coordinate independent?

If so, and a set of EOM are not invariant under coordinate transformations, does this mean that we cannot write down an action for them?

Comment: The Lagrangian of a arbitrary system is not *necessarily* coordinate independent. For example, if your particles are moving in an external potential, the Lagrangian is not independent of spatial coordinates.